# $ \lVert {\bf f} \rVert_{p} \leqslant (m(E))^{1-1/p} \lVert {\bf f} \rVert_{\infty} $ for any $ f \in L_{\infty}(E) $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

> If $m(E)$ is finite and ${\bf f}\in L_\infty(E)$ then for any $p\geqslant 1$, $$ \lVert {\bf f} \rVert_{p} \leqslant (m(E))^{1-1/p}  \lVert {\bf f} \rVert_{\infty} .$$

I tried to apply Hölder's inequality here but I am not sure whether that is the right path or not. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: The wording of your question was very confusing, so I changed it.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \int_E \lvert f \rvert^p \cdot 1 \leqslant \left(\sup_E \lvert f \rvert^p \right) \int_E 1 = \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}^p m(E), $$
since $\lVert \lvert f \rvert^p \rVert_{\infty} = \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}^p$. Therefore, taking $p$th roots,
$$ \lVert f \rVert_{p} \leqslant m(E)^{1/p}\lVert f \rVert_{\infty} $$
It has to be this because the equality case will occur if $f=1$; your inequality would give $m(E)^{1/p} \leqslant m(E)^{1-1/p}$, which is not true for every $p$ or possible value of $m(E)$.

Comment: good reasoning but I was wondering why my inequalities is not true.@ chappers

Comment: Suppose, for example, that $m(E)=2$. Then if we put $f=1$ into your version, we find $$2^{1/p}\leqslant 2^{1-1/p},$$
which rearranges into $4^{1/p} \leqslant 2$; this is obviously false for $1\leqslant p < 2$.